# grpc's ServerBuilder::AddListeningPort() always returns TCP port zero

Tags: c++, windows, grpc

I'm on Windows 10, VS2019, 64-bit grpc v1.23.1-1 installed via vcpkg.

Using grpc's `ServerBuilder` class.  From [the examples provided](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/cpp), the server code should look similar to this:

```
const std::string server_address = "0.0.0.0:12345";
int tcp_port;
grpc::ServerBuilder builder;
builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials(), &tcp_port);
builder.RegisterService(&myservice);
auto server(builder.BuildAndStart());
std::cout << "port=" << tcp_port << std::endl;
server->Wait();
```

No matter what I try to use for `server_address`, the resulting `tcp_port` is always zero, and calling netstat to view all listening ports confirms my application isn't listening anywhere.

The `AddListeningPort()` API is documented [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpcpp/server_builder_impl.h#L118).

Examples of addresses I've tried so far:

```
[::1]:54321
dns:///[::1]43210
dns:///::1:
::1
::1:
0.0.0.0:12345
localhost
localhost:7525
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1:9876
```

(I've tried dozens of random port numbers, not just the ones here, and netstat confirms I don't have anything bound to those ports.)

**Is there any way to get more information from grpc?  There doesn't seem to be any API to call within `grpc::Server` nor `grpc::ServerBuilder` to get an error code, status message, etc.**

---

**EDIT:**
For people googling things related to grpc in the future, I've edited the example code to move the `std::cout` line further down, since the port isn't valid until after the call to `BuildAndStart()`  (Thanks @Botje.)

Also determined why netstat on Windows wasn't showing me my application.  I was using this command:

```
netstat -q -b -n -p tcp
```

But to see IPv6/TCPv6, I needed this:

```
netstat -q -b -n -p tcpv6
```

Since the address was similar to this ipv6 loopback: `[::1]:12345`.

Note that you can call this more than once, so now I'm using something similar to these lines:

```
builder.AddListeningPort("127.0.0.1:12345", grpc::InsecureServerCredentials(), &tcp4_port);
builder.AddListeningPort("[::1]:12345", grpc::InsecureServerCredentials(), &tcp6_port);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation has this to say about `selected_port`:

> If not `nullptr`, gets populated with the port number bound to the `grpc::Server` for the corresponding endpoint **after it is successfully bound by `BuildAndStart()`**, 0 otherwise. `AddListeningPort` does not modify this pointer.

And for `addr_uri`:

> To bind to any address, please use IPv6 any, i.e., `[::]:<port>`, which also accepts IPv4 connections.

Try passing `"[::]:12345"` as `addr_uri` and only checking the value of `tcp_port` **after** calling `BuildAndStart`.

Comment: Serves me right for trying to get this done at 3am. I hadn't understood the "AddListeningPort does not modify this pointer" text until you pointed it out.